# Magento CE 2.0 Index Management Always Processing

Tags: magento2, indexer

How to fix Magento 2.0 Index Management stuck at processing state?

There's no var/lock to delete inside Magento 2 root directory, so old ways to fix this are obsolete.

Forcing with these new CLI didn't work either:

```
sudo -u www-data php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cache:flush
sudo -u www-data php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indexer status is stored in `indexer_state` table so try to update the status manually using:

```
update magento.indexer_state set status='invalid' where status ='working'
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex P, I'll give it a try later and let you know. :)

Comment: Alex P, it works! Thanks :D

Turned out it was causing by the latest update of php7.0-fpm in Ubuntu 14.04 exiting with SegFault every time the cron indexer ran.

Comment: This only changes the status of index. When i re-index again, the problem re-occurs. Any solution for that ?

Comment: Have you tried to get the latest [Magento 2.0.2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases/tag/2.0.2) release? It should be compatible with PHP 7 and no segmentation faults should occur anymore.

Comment: no i haven't tried that. I will check it, thank you.

Comment: sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't.  Is there something else that needs to be set in order to rebuild the index?

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this from the command line by reseting the index which will invalidate the state of the index and remove the processing flag from the index.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

Optionally you may also append the index name to the command to just just reset that index.

Comment: this command doesn't exist for me in 2.0.4